# Area of intersection of two general overlapping circles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, roots, analytic-geometry

My algebra is letting me down here, I can't figure out how to arrange this equation - anyone prepared to give me a hand?

The [area of the intersection of two circles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) can be defined as
 $$A = r^2 \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{d}{r}\right) - d \sqrt{r^2 - d^2} + R^2 \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{d}{R}\right) - d \sqrt{R^2 - d^2}$$
Where:

- $r$ is the radius of circle one
- $R$ is the radius of circle two
- $A$ is the area of their intersection
- $d$ is the distance between the two circles' centres.

But, if I have numerical values for all of these variables except $d$, how can I reform the equation to find it?

Comment: Something is wrong with your formula.  For $d=r=R$ it makes the area $0$.

Comment: The actual formula is equation $(14)$ or maybe $(10)$ of the question’s link

Comment: If someone find this question, then equation $(10)$ requires inverting $x-\cos(x)\sin(x)$ which is possible with [inverse of $\sin(x)+x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652277/inverse-of-fx-sinxx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to do this analitically. You can find $d$ only by a numerical method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm).

Comment: Ah ha! That'd explain it. Care to expand with recommendations as to which method(s) I should look at?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a specialist in  numerical methods. I think you will find experts in this site.  But first, I would advise to transform your question in such a way:     There is an equation $$B = F(\frac{d}{r})+ F(\frac{d}{R})$$ where $$F(x)=(x^2 \cos x)^{-1}-\sqrt{x^{-2} - 1}$$ (and besides  $B=Ad^{-2}$). Which is an appropriate numerical method to find $r$?