# Inverse of $f(x)=\sin(x)+x$

Tags: functions, closed-form, inverse-function, transcendental-equations, transcendental-functions

What is the inverse of

$$f(x)=\sin(x)+x.$$

I thought about it for a while but I couldn't figure it out and I couldn't find the answer on the internet.

What about

$$f(x)=\sin(a \cdot x)+x$$

where $a$ is a known real constant.

Thank you for taking the time to read this question!
Sorry if this has been asked before...

Comment: It's unlikely that the inverse of $f$ can be expressed using only elementary functions. Why do you need its inverse?

Comment: I don't think there is a nice closed form for the inverse. Depending on what you need it for, you could for instance derive Taylor expansions of the inverse at a certain point to see how it behaves locally.

Comment: @TMM I actually got to this trying to determinate this function... http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lyy8t4ihlt1qlc2l8o1_500.gif

Comment: Maybe "determinate" that using parametric equations...

Comment: For what it's worth, it is called a [cycloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid).

Comment: @GEdgar determine*, sorry...

Answer (score 11):

[Kepler's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation)  ... its solution is known not to be an elementary function.

Answer (score 6):

Why not give another “closed form” since @GEdgar’s solution for the Kepler equation technically has $E(a,M)$ as the solution in the [Wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation#/editor/9). Here is a solution to the inverse of $y=\sin(x)+x$ using mathematica function using [Inverse Beta Regularized](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseBetaRegularized.html) which is a standard function introduced in $1996$. The answer is from:

> [Closed form of $x$ for $x=\cos(x)$: Intuition for why the Dottie number is an inverse sine of the median of a Beta distribution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389528/closed-form-of-x-for-x-cosx-intuition-for-why-the-dottie-number-is-an-in)

where

> $$M=E-e\sin(E)\iff x=y-a\sin(y)\implies y=\text E(a,x)$$

and

> $$\text E(-1,x)=2\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\text I^{-1}_{\frac x\pi}\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)}=\text{hav}^{-1}\left(\text I^{-1}_{\frac x\pi}\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)\right)$$

Here is [**a numerical tester for the inverse function**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sin%28inversehaversine%28inversebetaregularized%28e%2Fpi%2C1%2F2%2C3%2F2%29%29%29%2B+inversehaversine%28inversebetaregularized%28e%2Fpi%2C1%2F2%2C3%2F2%29%29-e)

Here is a plot of:

$$\boxed{x=\sin(y)+y\implies y=\text E(-1,x) = \text{hav}^{-1}\left(\text I^{-1}_{\frac x\pi}\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)\right),0\le x\le \pi}: $$

[image]

The code is `inversehaversine(inversebetaregularized(x/pi,1/2,3/2))`

where appears the [Inverse Haversine](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHaversine.html), a transformed inverse sine function.

The [differential equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ddx+inversehaversine%28inversebetaregularized%28x%2Fpi%2C1%2F2%2C3%2F2%29%29) for the inverse of $y=\sin(x)+x$ is:

$$y’\text{vercos}(y))=1$$

where vercos is the [versed cosine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), a transformed cosine function. The inverse function’s domain is extended by using [**a series expansion of $\text I^{-1}_z(a,b)$**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseBetaRegularized/06/01/02/). Please correct me and give me feedback!

Unfortunately, it seems that no more solutions of the inverse of $x-a\sin(x)=y$ can be solved for using this method. The only exception is that the inverse of $x-\sin(x)$ can be given in closed form by switching the $\frac32$ and
$\frac12$ in the boxed answer.

Comment: Look https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467187/anti-dual-numbers-and-what-are-their-properties

Answer (score 3):

Using the fixed-point technique seems to be the simplest solution I found:

$y = x - \sin(y)$

$y = x - \sin(x - \sin(y))$

$y = x - \sin(x - \sin(x - \sin(y)))$

…

$y = x - \sin(x - \sin(x - \sin(x - \sin(x - ... \sin(y) ...))))$

You can assign any value to $y$ on the right side since the effect is eventually eliminated after numerous iterations of the sine operation.

Here are the plotted functions, where the $z$ slider represents the $y$ value on the right side of the equation:

[image: sin(x) + x inverse]

As observed, the source and inverse functions exhibit symmetry with respect to the line $y = x$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Mathjax tip `$\sin x$`= $\sin x$.

Answer (score 1):

That's a kind of [Kepler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation). Already Liouville proved that the inverse isn't an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function):

$$x+\sin(ax)=f(x)$$
$$x-(-1)\sin(ax)=f(x)$$
$x\to\frac{t}{a}$:
$$t-(-a)\sin(t)=af(x)$$

see [How to solve Kepler's equation $M=E-\varepsilon \sin E$ for $E$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/how-to-solve-keplers-equation-m-e-varepsilon-sin-e-for-e/4732665#4732665)

**1) Lambert W, Generalized Lambert W**

$$\sin(ax)+x=y$$

$$-\frac{1}{2}i\left(e^{aix}-e^{-aix}\right)+x=+y$$

$$-\frac{1}{2}i\left(e^{aix}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}i+e^{aix}x-e^{aix}y=0$$

$$e^{aix}=-ix\pm\sqrt{-x^2+2yx-y^2+1}+iy$$

We see, the inverse cannot be represented in closed form in terms of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) either, and not by generalized Lambert W of Mezö et. al. But possibly by other generalized Lambert W - see the references below.

**2) "Leal-functions"**

$$\sin(x)+x=y$$
because $\sin(it)=i\sinh(t)$: $x\to it$:
$$\sin(it)+it=y$$
$$i(\sinh(t)+t)=y$$
$$\sinh(t)+t=-iy$$
$$t=\text{Lsin}_2(-iy)$$
$$x=i\ \text{Lsin}_2(-iy)$$

[Mezö 2017] Mezö, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mezö/Baricz 2017] Mezö, I.; Baricz, A.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

[[Stoutemyer 2022] Stoutemyer, D. R.: Inverse spherical Bessel functions generalize Lambert W and solve similar equations containing trigonometric or hyperbolic subexpressions or their inverses. 2022](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.00707)

[[Vazquez-Leal et al. 2020] Vazquez-Leal, H.; Sandoval-Hernandez, M. A.; Filobello-Ninoa, U.: The novel family of transcendental Leal-functions with applications to science and engineering. Heliyon 6 (2020) (11) e05418](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405844020322611)