# Inverse of $f(x)= x+\sin(x)$?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

How to find the inverse of $f(x) = x+\sin(x)$, analytically?

Well how should I proceed to find the inverse of $f(x)$? Basically I have applied graphical approach to solve the equation, but I want to know the inverse equation by analytical method.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652277/inverse-of-fx-sinxx).

Comment: You are unlikely to be able to achieve much more than a series expansion which might start $\dfrac12 y + \dfrac1{96} y^3 +\dfrac{1}{1920} y^5+\cdots$

Answer (score -3):

Let $y = x + \sin x = f(x)$;
So, $x = f^{-1}(y)$. 
Differentiating the first expression according to $y$ leads to $x' + x'\cos(x) = 1$, or $x'(1+\cos x) = 1$.
Let us put $x=\arccos t$, so $x' = -t'/\sqrt{1-t^2}$. 
This leads to $-t'(1+t)/\sqrt{1-t^2} = 1$, or $t'=-\sqrt{\frac{1-t}{1+t}}$.
I believe that this is a standard differential equation. I don't know if it is solvable. If it is not, then the problem has no analytical closed expression.

Another way:
Using the formula $\cos x =  \frac{1-\tan^2(x/2)}{1+\tan^2(x/2)}$, we are lead to the differential equation $x' = \frac{1+\tan^2(x/2)}{2}$. We can put $u = \tan(x/2)$, so $u'=\frac{1}{2}x'(1+u^2)$, and $x' = \frac{2u'}{1+u^2}$. So, the equation becomes $u' = \frac{(1+u^2)^2}{4}$. If I'm not wrong, there is a method to handle somehow this kind of equations. I will try tomorrow.

Comment: Ooops, it's true. Let me say that it was to test the vigilance of the student :-) . My answer remains exact, with some care regarding imaginaries (I believe).

Comment: This is insufficient as an answer. Are you sure it leads to an explicit solution ? Can you exhibit it ?

Comment: Indeed, the hint was wrong. I have replaced it with another hint which is hopefully correct.

Comment: Sooo... $x=-i\ln t$ AND $x=\ln t$?

Comment: You pointed to a minor trailing assertion from a previous incorrect solution. This minor bug was corrected, but anyway, the solution is strange ; I don't find where is the problem (checking the solution directly shows that $x$ satisfies the differential equation $2x'+e^x + e^{-x} = 2$).

Comment: That's it. I found the problem from the very beginning. I'll try to correct this or vote to delete this post.