# Circular segment area inverse function - invert function of (x−sin(x))

Tags: circles, area

Computing the area of a circular segment (green part below) from a distance along the radius axis (like $h$, the [sagitta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagitta_(geometry)) distance) is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment).

[image: circular segment area]

What could be the inverse function, that is the $f$ function: $h=f(A)$, or an approximation of it ?

In other words: The circle is filled with a known quantity of a liquid ($A$) - what is the resulting liquid level ($h$) ?

**EDIT 1**

Considering that:

$h=R(1-\cos(\theta/2))$

and

$A=R^2/2.(\theta - \sin(\theta))$

I would simply need to express $\theta$ as a function of $A$, that is finding the invert function of $(x-\sin(x))$.

**EDIT 2**

According to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785772) pointed out by [Saad](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/302797/saad), it seems an algebraical expression of the inverse function cannot be obtained. An approximation would however be welcome.

**EDIT 3**

See the motivation behind this question here: https://observablehq.com/@jgaffuri/striped-circle

Comment: Related: [Why can't the inverse of $F(x)=x+\sin(x)$
have a formula algebraically?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785772).

Comment: @Saad: Thanks. It shows that I cannot expect to have an algebraical formula for this inverse. A 'fair' approximation would however be welcome.

Comment: An ODE area versus height would be an answer? By CAS an accurate    height for given volume ratio can be outputted.

Answer (score 2):

A decent approximate for the sine function over its full variation domain $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ is

$$\sin \theta = \frac{4\theta}\pi\left( 1- \frac \theta\pi\right)$$

(See the plot below.) Then, the area $A$ can be expressed as

$$A =\frac12 R^2\left( \theta - \sin\theta\right) = R^2\left[\left(\frac12-\frac2\pi\right)\theta + \frac2{\pi^2}\theta^2\right] $$

and the corresponding inverse function is

$$\theta(A) = \frac{\pi^2}4\left(\frac12-\frac2\pi\right) \left[\sqrt{1+\frac{32A}{(\pi-2)^2R^2}}-1\right]$$
[image]

Comment: From the plot it is clear $\frac{4\theta}{\pi} \left (1 - \frac{\theta}{\pi} \right ) \geqslant \sin \theta$ for $\theta \in [0,\pi]$, but can you give any hint how one might show this?

Comment: @omegadot - see the proof in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3632012/686284

Comment: That will do it, and thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Exact inversion is not possible because the equation is transcendental, so we have to resort to numerical methods.

We approximate the exact curve, in blue,

$$y=x-\sin x$$

in the range $[0,\pi]$. Other ranges follow by symmetry/periodicity.

Using the first two terms of the Taylor development, we get the green curve

$$y\approx \frac{x^3}6,$$ which matches the function well for small $x$.

For larger $x$, we can fix the deviation (up to $\dfrac{\pi^3}6$ instead of $\pi$) by adding a damping factor such that the function value is exact at $0$ and $\pi$. We also require that for small $x$, the formula remains asymptotically exact. For convenience, we chose the form $1-ax^3$ and obtained the magenta curve

$$y\approx\frac{x^3}6\left(1-\left(1-\dfrac6{\pi^2}\right)\frac{x^3}{\pi^3}\right).$$

[image]

As you can notice, both

$$y=ax^3$$ and $$y=ax^3(1-bx^3)$$ are easily inverted (for the second, solve the quadratic equation in $x^3$).

From these inital approximations, you can start Newton's iterations,

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n-\sin x_n-y}{1-\cos x_n}.$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: hi Claude. I should have mentioned (shame on me), that I want the approximation to be unbiased for small small $x$, i.e. the cubic coefficient should be $a=1/6$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I am not surprised to see a Padé approximant ;-) As usual, this is a matter of a tradeoff between accuracy and run-time cost, and can only be decided by timing tests on a real platform.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I see. Yep, the cubic equation can be solved with hyperbolic functions (just as is it solved with trigonometry in the casus irreductibilis). Amazing how early mathematicians could obtain such advanced results "with bare hands" !

Answer (score 1):

Considering
$$y=x-\sin(x)$$ you can develop the rhs as a Taylor series to get
$$y=\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{x^7}{5040}-\frac{x^9}{362880}+\frac{x^{11}}{399
   16800}-\frac{x^{13}}{6227020800}+O\left(x^{15}\right)\tag 1$$ and use series reversion to obtain
$$x=t+\frac{t^3}{60}+\frac{t^5}{1400}+\frac{t^7}{25200}+\frac{43
   t^9}{17248000}+\frac{1213 t^{11}}{7207200000}+O\left(t^{13}\right)\tag 2$$ where $t=\sqrt[3]{6y}$.

For sure, we can add as many terms as we wish for $(1)$ and then $(2)$ but we can make $(2)$ more compact transforming the series as a $[2n+1,2n]$ Padé approximant which will be at least as accurate as a Taylor series to $O\left(t^{4n+2}\right)$. For conveniency, they will be written as
$$P_n=t \,\frac{1+\sum _{i=1}^n a_i\,t^{2 i}  } {1+\sum _{i=1}^n b_i\,t^{2 i}}$$ For example
$$P_1=t\,\frac{1-\frac{11}{420} t^2} {1-\frac{3 }{70}t^2 }$$
$$P_2=t\,\frac{1-\frac{1493 }{21120}t^2+\frac{167 }{268800}t^4 } {1-\frac{123 }{1408}t^2+\frac{403 }{295680}t^4 }$$
For testing purposes, assign a value to $x$, compute the corresponding $y$ and $t$ and recompute $x_{(n)}$  given by $P_n$ . Below are the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x_{\text{given}} & x_{(1)} & x_{(2)}  & x_{(3)} \\
 0.1 & 0.100000000 & 0.100000000 & 0.100000000 \\
 0.2 & 0.200000000 & 0.200000000 & 0.200000000 \\
 0.3 & 0.299999998 & 0.300000000 & 0.300000000 \\
 0.4 & 0.399999985 & 0.400000000 & 0.400000000 \\
 0.5 & 0.499999929 & 0.500000000 & 0.500000000 \\
 0.6 & 0.599999745 & 0.600000000 & 0.600000000 \\
 0.7 & 0.699999248 & 0.700000000 & 0.700000000 \\
 0.8 & 0.799998082 & 0.800000000 & 0.800000000 \\
 0.9 & 0.899995616 & 0.899999999 & 0.900000000 \\
 1.0 & 0.999990812 & 0.999999995 & 1.000000000 \\
 1.1 & 1.099982049 & 1.099999986 & 1.100000000 \\
 1.2 & 1.199966902 & 1.199999964 & 1.200000000 \\
 1.3 & 1.299941871 & 1.299999913 & 1.300000000 \\
 1.4 & 1.399902050 & 1.399999801 & 1.400000000 \\
 1.5 & 1.499840739 & 1.499999570 & 1.499999999 \\
 1.6 & 1.599748976 & 1.599999116 & 1.599999997 \\
 1.7 & 1.699615013 & 1.699998260 & 1.699999992 \\
 1.8 & 1.799423695 & 1.799996701 & 1.799999981 \\
 1.9 & 1.899155774 & 1.899993951 & 1.899999957 \\
 2.0 & 1.998787130 & 1.999989239 & 1.999999906 \\
 2.1 & 2.098287918 & 2.099981371 & 2.099999800 \\
 2.2 & 2.197621631 & 2.199968535 & 2.199999590 \\
 2.3 & 2.296744092 & 2.299948039 & 2.299999183 \\
 2.4 & 2.395602386 & 2.399915947 & 2.399998417 \\
 2.5 & 2.494133744 & 2.499866600 & 2.499997012 \\
 2.6 & 2.592264408 & 2.599791977 & 2.599994490 \\
 2.7 & 2.689908485 & 2.699680877 & 2.699990060 \\
 2.8 & 2.786966855 & 2.799517867 & 2.799982431 \\
 2.9 & 2.883326151 & 2.899281948 & 2.899969535 \\
 3.0 & 2.978857863 & 2.998944916 & 2.999948113
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

As a Padé like approximant, 
$$x=t \, \frac{1-\frac{1267 }{9428}t^2+\frac{31}{6507}t^4-\frac{1}{32473} t^6} {1-\frac{2251}{14902}t^2+\frac{63 }{9593}t^4-\frac{1}{13890}t^6}\qquad (t=\sqrt[3]{6y})$$ leads to errors lower than $10^{-7}$ over all the range.

Comment: Thank you Claude - I could finally find some time to use it, see here: https://observablehq.com/@jgaffuri/striped-circle

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to add another answer since it is based on a totally different approach.*

"Thanks" to the containment, I wondered what we could get using the superb approximation
$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad \qquad(0\leq x\leq\pi)$$  proposed, more than $1,400$ years ago, by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician.

This leads to a cubic equation in $x$
$$4 x^3-4  (y+\pi -4)x^2+\pi\left(4   y+5 \pi -16 \right)x-5 \pi ^2 y=0$$
Let $t=y+\pi-4$
$$4 x^3-4 t x^2+\pi\left(4   t+\pi \right) x-5 \pi ^2 (t+4-\pi)=0$$ which has only one real root as soon as $y > 0.016$; we can compute the solution using the hyperbolic method.

The nasty but amazing result is

$$x=\frac t 3 -2 P(t) \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{Q(t)}{\big[P(t)\big]^3}\right)\right)$$ where
$$P(t)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi ^2}{12}+\frac{\pi  }{3}t-\frac{1}{9}t^2}$$ $$Q(t)=\frac{5}{8} (\pi -4) \pi ^2-\frac{7 \pi ^2 }{12}t+\frac{\pi }{6}t^2-\frac{1}{27}t^3$$ which gives quite good results as soon as $y>1-\sin(1)\sim 0.16$.

Repeating the same procedure as in my other answer
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x_{\text{given}} & x_{\text{calc}} \\
 1.0 & 0.99726 \\
 1.1 & 1.09810 \\
 1.2 & 1.19884 \\
 1.3 & 1.29941 \\
 1.4 & 1.39978 \\
 1.5 & 1.49996 \\
 1.6 & 1.59999 \\
 1.7 & 1.69990 \\
 1.8 & 1.79974 \\
 1.9 & 1.89954 \\
 2.0 & 1.99936 \\
 2.1 & 2.09922 \\
 2.2 & 2.19917 \\
 2.3 & 2.29921 \\
 2.4 & 2.39936 \\
 2.5 & 2.49961 \\
 2.6 & 2.59994 \\
 2.7 & 2.70029 \\
 2.8 & 2.80061 \\
 2.9 & 2.90081 \\
 3.0 & 3.00076 \\
 3.1 & 3.10033
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Due to their transcendental nature an exact inverse relation cannot be defined. A numerical iteration supplies exact heights.

In the following a differential equation approach is chosen and set up in  *Mathematica*. Started with parametrization on $t$ but ended up as normal ODE to output height $h$ as dependent variable. It is integrated to read off y-axis water heights at desired x-axis volume fraction of cylindrical tank ( three outputs shown) :

$$ x= \dfrac{A}{\pi R^2}=\dfrac{t-\sin t}{2 \pi};\, y= \dfrac{h}{R}=1-\cos t/2\, $$ 
$$ x'=\dfrac{1 - \cos t}{2 \pi}; \,y'= \dfrac12 \,\sin t/2 $$

$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y'}{x'}=\pi \dfrac {\sqrt{1-(1-y)^2}}{2 ( 1- \cos^2 t/2})= \dfrac{\pi/2}{\sqrt{y(1-y)}}$$

```
 niveau = {Y'[x] == (Pi/2)/Sqrt[Y[x] (2 - Y[x])], Y[0] == 10^-8};
    NDSolve[niveau, Y, {x, 0, xm}];
    y[u_] = Y[u] /. First[%];
    Plot[y[x], {x, 0., 1}, GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, Axes -> True, 
     AxesLabel -> {AreaFraction, Height}]
    {y[0.2].y[0.6], y[0.85]}
    ParametricPlot[{(t - Sin[t])/(2 Pi), (1 - Cos[t/2])}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, GridLines -> Automatic,
      Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {AreaFraction, Height}]
```

[image]

Integrated and direct plots are seen to be *identical*.