# Divide a circle into n segments of equal area where all segments share a common point on the circumference of the circle

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Divide a circle into n segments of equal area where all segments share a common point on the circumference of the circle.

The segments must be created by drawing straight lines from a common point on the circumference to the point at which they intersect the circumference again. Each segment must have an equal area.

I am adding the simplest case [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqSSy.png) in the event that my description is unclear (wanting A, B, C to have equal areas in the attached image).

The use case here is agricultural - a single gate opening into several fields of equal area so it doesn't need to be mathematically perfect, just close enough - I would be happy with an approach which minimized the difference in the area of n segments inside the circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Let us take the common point as the origin. Let $R$ be the radius of the circle, with its origin in $(R,0)$.

The polar equation of this circle is

$$\rho=f(\theta)=2R\cos \theta, \ -\pi/2 < \theta < +\pi/2.$$

The area "browsed" by the radius between $\theta_k$ and $\theta_{k+1}$ (for $1 \le k \le n-1$) is

$$\int_{\theta_k}^{\theta_{k+1}}\frac12 f(\theta)^2 d\theta$$ $$=2R^2\int_{\theta_k}^{\theta_{k+1}}(\cos \theta)^2 d\theta$$
$$=R^2\int_{\theta_k}^{\theta_{k+1}}(1+\cos 2\theta) d\theta$$
$$=R^2 \underbrace{(\theta+\frac12 \sin(2\theta))}_{f(\theta)}]_{\theta_k}^{\theta_{k+1}}$$
$$=R^2\left(f(\theta_{k+1})-f(\theta_k)\right)\tag{1}$$

Therefore, this issue is brought back to the division of line segment $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ into $n$ equal parts by  function $f$.

If $n$ is the number of "zones", we know that each area is equal to $\frac{\pi R^2}{n}$. Therefore we have to find a sequence of values $\theta_k$ such that :

$$f(\theta_{k+1})-f(\theta_k)=\frac{\pi}{n}\tag{2}$$

$f$ is in fact invertible on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ because $f'(\theta)>0$ on this interval. Therefore, we can write recurrence (2) under the form :

$$\theta_{k+1}=f^{-1}\left(f(\theta_k)+\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\tag{3}$$

This recurrence works because :

- we know the initial value $\theta_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$.
- though $f^{-1}$ hasn't an analytic expression, its values $\theta=f^{-1}(u)$ can be computed by solving equation $f(\theta)=u$ by definition of an inverse function.

Here is a Matlab implementation (where inverse function $f^{-1}$ is denoted $g$ and computed as a separate function).

```
 function main
 clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal;
 u=0:pi/100:2*pi;plot(1+cos(u),sin(u),'r');
 n=26;
 f=@(t)(t+0.5*sin(2*t));
 t=-pi/2; % \theta_0
 for k=1:n-1
    t=g(f(t)+pi/n); % implem. of formula (3)
    plot([0,1+cos(2*t)],[0,sin(2*t)]);
 end;
 function t=g(u);
 syms t1
 X=solve(t1+0.5*sin(2*t1)==u);
 t=X(1);
```

Remark : In fact, this answer can be considered as "issued" from the answer I had given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2262994/305862) to a completely similar question. The formulation of this answer wasn't direct enough (this explains maybe why it hadn't been upvoted) ; I think the present version, with its accompanying program, is clearer.

Comment: Hi Jean-Marie ! It seems that you enjoy polar coordinates (which are so nice in ... most cases). Cheers

Comment: Yes, this is a nice clean solution. I am working on a python snippet to implement this - I will add in once complete.

Comment: I have done a huge error in the definition of function $f$. Now corrected. I apologize for the trouble it can have caused.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Hi, Claude, will polar angles remain the same with climate changes ?

Comment: Yes. and I am aware that there are other ways to solve it without using a "solve" black box, in particular plainly by using fixed point theorem...

Comment: The range of $t$ is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: I proposed an analytic approximation

Comment: "The formulation of this answer wasn't direct enough (this explains maybe why it hadn't been upvoted)" - I did not at that point in time have sufficient karma to upvote, only to accept the solution. I have up-voted now.

Answer (score 2):

For the solution of
$$t+\frac 12 \sin(2t)=u$$ I shall use my favored $\large 1,400^+$ years old approximation od the sine function.

This boils down to the solution of the cubic equation
$$t^3+bt^2+ct+d=0$$ where
$$b=-\left(u+2+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\qquad\qquad c=\frac{\pi}{16}   (8 (u+2)+5 \pi )\qquad\qquad d=-\frac{5 \pi ^2 }{16}u$$

Let
$$p=c-\frac{b^2}{3}\qquad \qquad q=\frac{2 b^3}{27}-\frac{b c}{3}+d$$ and the solution is given by
$$t=-2\sqrt{\frac p 3}\sinh\left(\frac 13 \text{arcsinh}\left(\frac {3q}{2p} \sqrt{\frac 3 p } \right)  \right)-\frac b 3$$
Checking for a few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
u & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.1 & 0.049723 &  0.050042 \\
 0.2 & 0.099924 &  0.100336 \\
 0.3 & 0.150791 &  0.151146 \\
 0.4 & 0.202548 &  0.202756 \\
 0.5 & 0.255464 &  0.255487 \\
 0.6 & 0.309876 &  0.309715 \\
 0.7 & 0.366206 &  0.365897 \\
 0.8 & 0.425013 &  0.424614 \\
 0.9 & 0.487048 &  0.486635 \\
 1.0 & 0.553379 &  0.553030 \\
 1.1 & 0.625606 &  0.625386 \\
 1.2 & 0.706320 &  0.706251 \\
 1.3 & 0.800223 &  0.800220 \\
 1.4 & 0.917578 &  0.917297 \\
 1.5 & 1.091410 &  1.089880 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: A $\approx 4.10^{-4}$ approximation... Good job. More than enough for field sharing !

Comment: @JeanMarie. Using a 1400 years old approximation