# How can I solve $y'+\sin y'=x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have no idea how to start with this. I tried taking the derivative and making use of $\cos{y'}^2+\sin{y'}^2=1$ but it seems to get even more confusing. Of course we can replace $y'$ with $f$ since $y$ does not appear but that's as far as I can get.

Comment: How far have you gotten in diff eq?

Comment: I've taken a full course on ODEs and another one on PDEs.

Comment: Your observation that this is $f(x) + \sin(f(x)) = x$ is about as far as I would expect can be done on this problem, as I don't think you can invert the function $f + \sin(f)$. This is now no longer a question about ODEs or PDEs.

Comment: This was a question in a previous exam on the course I'm having. So there has to be a way to solve this .

Comment: @JohnKatsantas : You seem to have a lot of faith in exams!

Comment: Haha, I'm supposed to have in my teacher. Hopefully this doesn't drop in the exam today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem that you can get some elementary function. Write $F(t) = t+\sin t$, then it is

$$ F(y') = x\Rightarrow y' = F^{-1}(x) \Rightarrow y = \int F^{-1}(x) dx.$$

It seems that's the best you have, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652277/inverse-of-fx-sinxx) for $F$.