# How to solve the equation $x + \sin x = A$?

Tags: trigonometry, roots, inverse-function

How to solve the equation $x + \sin x = A$?

I have tried Wolfram Alpha, with no success.

I would be satisfied with an answer in special functions.

The context is, I was trying to find an expression for the coordinates $(x,y)$ for a number given with modulus and argument in the second system in [MO post #423657.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423657/)

I also tried to solve `Reduce[{(a^2 + b^2)/a == r,    1/4 (ArcTan[b/a] + (a b)/(a^2 + b^2) ) == arg}, {a, b}]` in Mathematica, but it took 10 hours after which I manually aborted.

Comment: For a specific value of $A$, probably numerically.

Comment: Try [this inverse function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652277/inverse-of-fx-sinxx/4390291#4390291). Also what is the context of the problem and what have you tried? Your question may be closed for these reasons.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Hello! The context is, I was trying to find an expression for the coordinates $(x,y)$ for a number given with modulus and argument in the second system in this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423657/lemniscate-numbers-and-others-what-would-be-the-properties

Comment: @TymaGaidash in that system, $\int_0^{\phi } \cos ^2(t) \, dt=\operatorname{arg} z$. So to find the coordinates we have to find the angle $\phi$ from known arg.

Comment: $f(x)=x+\sin x$ is increasing since $f'(x)=1+\cos x \geq 0$. It follows that there is a unique solution of $x+\sin x=A$ and it lies in the inverval $[A-1,A+1]$. Once you restrict to such interval, you may apply a numerical method like the secant method or the secant-tangent method.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio definitely, a numerical method should work, but I want a closed form for a post here about the properties of this numerical system. If I post without a closed form, as I did, I get downvotes.

Comment: I also tried to solve `Reduce[{(a^2 + b^2)/a == r, 
  1/4 (ArcTan[b/a] + (a b)/(a^2 + b^2) ) == arg}, {a, b}]` in Mathematica, but it took 10 hours after which I manually aborted.

Comment: If you apply the Lagrange inversion theorem you can write the inverse function as a power series, with the caveat that its coefficients are increasingly harder to be computed.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Wow! that function in your post is indeed on spot!

Comment: @TymaGaidash okay, so if I am not mistaken, $x=\frac{\sqrt{1-I_{\frac{4 \arg (z)}{\pi }}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right){}^2} \sqrt{\left| 1-I_{\frac{4 \arg (z)}{\pi }}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right){}^2\right| }}{\arcsin \left(I_{\frac{4 \arg (z)}{\pi }}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)}$ and $y=\frac{I_{\frac{4 \arg (z)}{\pi }}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right) \sqrt{\left| 1-I_{\frac{4 \arg (z)}{\pi }}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right){}^2\right| }}{\arcsin\left(I_{\frac{4 \arg (z)}{\pi }}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)}$

Comment: @TymaGaidash https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+x%2Bcos+x+sin+x%3D%3DA

Comment: @TymaGaidash it is from your post. I will make a new post about this algebraic system with divisors of infinity!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136848/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-anixx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for:

$$\int_0^\phi \cos^2(t) dt=\frac14(2\phi+\sin(2\phi))=\arg(z)$$

Therefore:

$2\phi+\sin(2\phi)=4\arg(z)$

Using

[Inverse of $\sin(x)+x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652277/inverse-of-fx-sinxx/4390291#4390291)

the result is:

$$\boxed{\phi=\frac12\text{hav}^{-1}\left(\text I^{-1}_{\frac{4\arg(z)}\pi}\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)\right)}$$

if the argument is satisfied for

$0\le \frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}+\text{sgn}(b)\text{Abs}\left(\tan^{-1}(a,b)\right)\le \pi$ for $\arg(z)=\arg(a,b)= \frac14\left(\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}+\text{sgn}(b)\text{Abs}\left(\tan^{-1}(a,b)\right)\right)$

then the formula

> [works](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=eulergamma-1%2F2+inversehaversine%28inversebetaregularized%284+*1%2F4%282+eulergamma%2Bsin%282eulergamma%29%29%2Fpi%2C1%2F2%2C3%2F2%29%29)

Comment: I use this: `arg[a_, b_] := 1/4 ((a b)/(a^2 + b^2) + Sign[b] Abs[ArcTan[a, b]])`

Comment: Finally, I made it working. Please wait a few minutes.