# $y = x+\sin(x)$ Solid of Revolution y-axis with implicit function.

Tags: solid-of-revolution, implicit-function

Given the equation $y = x + \sin(x)$, as far as I am aware, an explicit equation $x = f(y)$ can not be found. Is there still a way to compute the volume of the solid of revolution of this function rotated about the y-axis, because the volume of the solid of revolution about the x-axis can be found ($V = \pi \int (x + \sin(x))^2 dx$). Considering $x = f(y)$ this "function" appears to have points with infinite slope on integer multiples of the point $(\pi,\pi)$ which may also complicate the computation of the solid of revolution.

[Graph of $y = x + \sin(x)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJdni.png)

Comment: You could express y as a Taylor series in x and invert it to obtain x as a function of y. The "infinite slope" should not present a problem, as the volume (between finite limits) is finite.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652277/inverse-of-fx-sinxx?noredirect=1) for inverses of $x+\sin(x)$. You could also try an inverse substitution like $x\to f^{-1}(x)$ to remove the inverse function from the integrand

Comment: You can actually slice the region in a particular way to avoid using inverses.

Comment: One could try $\int\pi x^2\,\mathrm{d}y=\int\pi x^2(1+\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Using the substitution dy = (1 + cos(x))dx in the integral produces an anti-derivative that shares many similar terms with the cylindrical shell method and substituting f(x) with f(b) - f(x). However it is not exactly the same and does not produce the same answer, except in the case when the lower bound a is set equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You've not specified a bounded region or interval over which to compute the volume of revolution, but in general, we can use the method of cylindrical shells to compute the volume when the cross-section is rotated about the $y$-axis.  So if $f$ does not have a closed-form inverse, we can still compute the volume as

$$V_1(a,b) = \int_{x=a}^b 2\pi x f(x) \, dx,$$ for some suitable interval satisfying $0 \le a < b$, whereas the volume of the region rotated about the $x$-axis is given by the method of disks/washers; e.g.,

$$V_2(a,b) = \int_{x=a}^b \pi f(x)^2 \, dx$$ where $f \ge 0$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: This cylindrical shell method finds the volume of the area between the x-axis and f(x) rotated about the y-axis which is close to what I was looking for. I found that by substituting in the integral f(x) with f(b) - f(x) (where b is the upper bound of integration) the volume between the y-axis and f(x) rotated about the y-axis is found which is what I was looking to compute.