# How do I simplify the formula for the time taken to fall from height '$r$' to height '$x$' to solve for height '$x$'?

Tags: trigonometry, physics

$\displaystyle t = \frac{ \frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin \Big( \sqrt{ \frac{x}{r} }\Big) + \sqrt{ \frac{x}{r} \ ( 1 - \frac{x}{r} ) } }{ \sqrt{ 2 \mu } } \, r^{3/2}$

This is an equation from [Equations for a falling body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_for_a_falling_body) for falling from height *r* to height *x* with a standard gravitational parameter *μ*, solving for time *t*. What I need help with is how to rewrite the equation to solve for *x* instead if I have time *t*, standard gravitational parameter *μ* and height *r* already.

I have been able to multiply both sides by the square root of 2*μ* and divide by *r* to the 1.5 power. Then I subtract $\pi/2$, but I am stuck with the square roots that have $x/r$ in them.

Comment: Not all equations can be solved analytically. I'm sure this one can't.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Would it possibly be because of the arcsin?

Comment: @Pyrania Let $\frac xr=\cos^2(y)$ and $\frac {\sqrt{2\mu}}{r^\frac32}=b$. The equation becomes $y+\frac12\sin(2y)=b$ which is solvable with [this Mathematica function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4390291/905886). If wanted, you can solve with the [Kepler equation Fourier series solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation). Which solution would you prefer?

Comment: @TymaGaidash The mathematica function please.

Answer (score 2):

Rearranging:
$$ t = \frac{ \cos^{-1}\Big( \sqrt{ \frac{x}{r} }\Big) + \sqrt{ \frac{x}{r} \ ( 1 - \frac{x}{r} ) } }{ \sqrt{ 2 \mu } } \, r^\frac32\mathop \iff^{\frac x r=w} \cos^{-1}(\sqrt w)+\sqrt{w(1-w)}=\frac{\sqrt{2\mu}}{r^\frac32}t=b$$

Applying the [regularized beta integral representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=betaregularized+integral+representation):

$$\cos^{-1}(\sqrt w)+\sqrt{w(1-w)}=\frac\pi2\int_0^{1-w}\frac{\sqrt u}{\sqrt{1-u}}du=\frac\pi 2\operatorname 1-I_w\left(\frac32,\frac12\right)=b$$

Therefore Mathematica’s [inverse beta regularized applied](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Inverse+beta+regularized):

$$x=r\operatorname I^{-1}_{1-\frac{2 \sqrt{2u}}{\pi r^{3/2}}}\left(\frac12,\frac32\right),0\le \frac{2 \sqrt{2u}}{\pi r^{3/2}} \le 1$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=evaluate+acos%28%E2%88%9A%28x%2Fr%29%29%2B%E2%88%9A%28%28x%2Fr%29%281-x%2Fr%29%29%2Cx%3D+r+InverseBetaRegularized%281-%282*0.8%29%2F%CF%80%2C+3%2F2%2C+1%2F2%29). If $\frac xr=\cos^2\left(\frac y2\right)$ instead, you would get $y+\sin(y)=2b$, a special case of Kepler’s equation for which there are series/integral representations [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/how-to-solve-keplers-equation-m-e-varepsilon-sin-e-for-e/4733405#4733405)

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\sqrt\frac{x}{r}=\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)$

$$\begin{align}t &= \frac{ \frac{\pi}{2} - \sin^{-1} y + y\sqrt{ 1 - y^2 } }{ \sqrt{ 2 \mu } } \, r^{3/2}\\
\frac{t\sqrt{2\mu}}{r^{3/2}} -\frac{\pi}{2} &=   - \sin^{-1} y + y\sqrt{ 1 - y^2 }\\
\frac{t\sqrt{2\mu}}{r^{3/2}} -\frac{\pi}{2} &=   \frac{\sin\phi-\phi}{2}\\
\frac{2t\sqrt{2\mu}}{r^{3/2}} -\pi=g(t,r,\mu)&=\sin\phi-\phi
\end{align}$$

If you could solve for $\phi$ you'd get $$x(\phi)=r\sin^2\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)$$

For $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le\phi\le \frac{\pi}{2}$, or $0\leq x\leq \frac{r}{2}$, a good approximation using the Taylor series becomes

$$g(t,r,\mu)\approx-\frac{\phi^3}{6}\implies x\approx r\sin^2\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{3\pi r^{3/2}-6t\sqrt{2\mu}}{4r^{3/2}}}\right)\quad\text{if}\;0\le\frac{x}{r}\le\frac{1}{2}$$

Note that increasing the upper bound of $\phi$ to $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ which gives $\frac{x}{r} \leq \frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4}=0.853\dots$, could still give a reasonable result depending on your application

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$k=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2\mu}  t}{r^{3/2}}\qquad \text{and}\qquad x=r\,y^2$$

The equation becomes
$$k=\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{y^2}\right)-\sqrt{y^2-y^4}\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{y^2}\right)-\sqrt{y^2-y^4}$$

Considering the positive solution
$$k=\sin ^{-1}(y)-y \sqrt{1-y^2}$$

Using Taylor series, the rhs is
$$\sin ^{-1}(y)-y \sqrt{1-y^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\, y^{2n+1}$$ where the first coefficients are

$$ \left\{\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{5},\frac{3}{28},\frac{5}{72},\frac{35}{
   704},\frac{63}{1664},\frac{77}{2560},\frac{429}{17408},\frac{643
   5}{311296},\frac{12155}{688128}\right\}  $$

but this would require solving very high degree polynomial equations.

But, the simplest Padé approximant
$$ \sin ^{-1}(y)-y \sqrt{1-y^2}\sim  \frac{20 y^3}{30-9 y^2}$$ whose error is $\frac{33 y^7}{700}$ reduces, for an *approximation*, the problem to a cubic equation in $y$
$$20 y^3+ 9k y^2-30 k=0$$ whose discriminant is negative; so, only one real root. For  $0 \leq k\leq \frac 12$
$$y=\frac{3}{20} k \left(2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2000}{9 k^2}-1\right)\right)-1\right)$$  is a decent *approximation* of the solution.

For better, we can use more terms for the Taylor series and then use power series reversion to obtain

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\, u^{2n+1}\qquad \text{where} \qquad u=\sqrt[3]{ \frac{3k}2}$$  the first coefficients being
$$\left\{1,-\frac{1}{10},-\frac{19}{1400},-\frac{71}{25200},-\frac{17
   753}{25872000},-\frac{1312063}{7207200000},-\frac{647915701}{127
   13500800000}\right\}$$

A few numbers
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} &\text{solution} \\
 0.1 & 0.515718 &  0.515718 \\
 0.2 & 0.637418 &  0.637418 \\
 0.3 & 0.717212 &  0.717212 \\
 0.4 & 0.776602 &  0.776601 \\
 0.5 & 0.823347 &  0.823346 \\
 0.6 & 0.861235 &  0.861232 \\
 0.7 & 0.892424 &  0.892416 \\
 0.8 & 0.918267 &  0.918248 \\
 0.9 & 0.939666 &  0.939627 \\
 1.0 & 0.957253 &  0.957180\\
 1.1 & 0.971482 &  0.971350 \\
 1.2 & 0.982685 &  0.982458 \\
 1.3 & 0.991109 &  0.990734 \\
 1.4 & 0.996938 &  0.996338 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$