# Cutting a circle into $n$ equal parts using vertical lines only

Tags: calculus, geometry

If I want to cut a circle into $n$ equal parts,

For example:
[image]

In this case ($n=3$), $x_1≈-0.264$ and $x_2≈0.264$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are values that sactisfy $\int_{-1}^{x_1}\sqrt{1-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{1-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{x_2}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}\mathrm{d}x$

And my problem is to find a generalised formula for $x_1,x_2,x_3...x_{n-1}$ when I cut the circle into $n$ equal parts.

The furthest I have gone is that $x_1$ is a value that sactisfy $\arcsin{(x_1)}+x_1\sqrt{1-x_1^2}=\frac{\pi}{n}-\frac{\pi}{2}$ which I couldn't solve for $x_1$

Comment: Do you have a reason to think a formula for the answer exists?

Comment: If you have a formula for $x_1,$ then you have determined the area $\pi/n$ and the angle $\alpha$ at the center of the segment. This is a function of the angle $\alpha$ and sine of the angle $\sin(\alpha)$. I do not see how you can solve this in a closed algebraic expression. It is probably out of reach for compass and straightedge, and likely also for more general algebraic expressions.

Comment: There is a calculator for doing this at https://planetcalc.com/8943/ and they also give the equations (but they note that the equations can't be solved algebraically, only numerically). E.g., for a circle of radius $100$ cut into seven equal pieces, the widths of the pieces, to two decimal places, are $40.09,25.56,23.10,22.49,23.10,25.56,40.09$.

Comment: Your equation is a [Kepler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) as if $x=\sin(w)$, then the equation to solve is $w+\sin(w)\cos(w)=\frac\pi n+\frac \pi 2$. There is a Mathematica closed form and linked integral/series representations in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748124/how-do-i-simplify-the-formula-for-the-time-taken-to-fall-from-height-r-to-he/4748252#4748252)

Comment: Are you talking about the circle (so equal arclengths) or the disk (so equal areas)? It is not clear without reading on. This is a typical confusion with the ambiguity of the word *circle*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n$ equal parts, the values of positive $x_k$'s are the solutions of the equation you wrote

$$\arcsin{(x_k)}+x_k\sqrt{1-x_k^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}-k\frac{\pi}{n}$$

I shall use $x=x_k$ and $A=\frac{\pi}{2}$$-k\frac{\pi}{n}$

A quite good approximation of the lhs is given by almost the simplest Padé approximant of it built around $x=0$, that is to say

$$\arcsin{(x)}+x\sqrt{1-x^2} \sim \frac{2 x \left(19 x^2-60\right)}{9 x^2-60}$$ whose error is $\frac{29 }{2800}x^7$.

To give an idea, consider the norm

$$\Phi=\int_{-1}^{+1} \Bigg(\arcsin{(x)}+x\sqrt{1-x^2}- \frac{2 x \left(19 x^2-60\right)}{9 x^2-60}  \Bigg)^2\,dx=1.10061\times 10^{-4}$$

So, an *approximation* is given by the solution of the cubic equation
$$38 x^3-9 A x^2-120 x+60A=0$$
which has three real roots.

Using the trigonometric solution, the solution to be retained (positive and smaller than $1$) is given by

$$x=\frac{1}{38} \left(3 A-2 \sqrt{9 A^2+1520} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3}
   \left(\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 A \left(9
   A^2-12160\right)}{\left(9 A^2+1520\right)^{3/2}}\right)+\pi
   \right)\right)\right) $$

For example, for $n=7$, the results would be

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
  \pm 0.112437 &  \pm 0.112437 \\
  \pm 0.343474 &  \pm 0.343478 \\
  \pm 0.598821 &  \pm 0.599061 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Another solution would be possible : expand the lhs as a series

$$\arcsin{(x)}+x\sqrt{1-x^2} =\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m\, x^{2m+1}$$

Truncate to some order and use power series reversion to obtain
$$x=\sum_{m=0}^\infty b_m\, A^{2m+1}$$  where the first coefficients are

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{48},\frac{13}{3840},\frac{493}{645120
   },\frac{37369}{185794560},\frac{4732249}{81749606400},\frac{90
   1188997}{51011754393600}\right\}$$

Comment: Did you prewrite this answer? You wrote it 1 minute after your previous answer.

Comment: @TymaGaidash. I have been unable to post anything for a week but the work was done. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how did you find out the first equation? I was only able to find it for $x_1$ but you generalised it into $x_k$ for natural numbers $k$